# Is there any benefit of using Anaconda for PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

Is there any benefit of using Anaconda for PyCharm instead of the standard python distribution for PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Anaconda instead of standard Python will benefit you as Anaconda comes with preinstalled packages. A lot of time will be saved there since installing various packages and making them run gets irritating sometimes.

Also, since it will have preinstalled packages, it can be heavy for your system. You can try miniconda as an alternative where you install packages when required. It is still better than having Python only. You can even install Anaconda by using `conda install anaconda`

Answer (score 2):

Pip installation of Python packages sometimes may cause few problems to the user and you need to constantly update the pip as well before installing any other python packages via pip. So using Anaconda will be a benefit in this case.